# Blazor server Application Authentication without Identity Server

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

How can I login in my Blazor Server application in exiting database login system (I don't want to use identity server and JWT token).Please give me suggest with full login system.

Answer (score 4):

Since Blazor server runs in an ASP.NET core app, You can use Cookie authentication, or JWT. I suggest you Cookie authentication since it's more simple to use. You just need to add

```
services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddCookies();
```

On your Startup.cs and add

```
app.UseAuthentication();
```

The Main difference between this and Identity it's the manage of the http responses inside the components.

[Here](https://blazorhelpwebsite.com/ViewBlogPost/36) it's a post of how to implement it! Hope it helps you!

Comment: Thank you for your feed back. This is Startup page but what will done by login button click.

Comment: Check on The Link that explain all the implementation, With the login button you Will call a method that first, clear the cookies (await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme); Then you will set your claims and finally you will use await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,claims, authProperties);

With cookies you will use httpContext.SignInAsync / SignOutAsync and also with Request.Cookies of the httpContext you will know who is the current user and if it's authenticated

Comment: Thank you for your feedback and this working for me, But small confuse when login credential not valid how to return LocalRedirect(returnUrl); with message (I am working 2 layout, 1 for login another for Mainlayout)

Comment: @shafaetjsr if this works for you please consider it as an answer for other people!

Comment: The linked article is now marked as being outdated. Things move fast in Blazor, it's hard to find up to date information.